# Criar arquivos numerados em ordem

Tags: php

Bem, estou querendo fazer algo que crie arquivos com numeração, por exemplo:

`001.txt`, `002.txt`, `003.txt` [...] `200.txt`...

Ou seja, se o arquivo 001.txt existir, criar o 002.txt e assim por diante.

É possível?

Comment: Você quer dizer se o arquivo 001.txt existir então crie arquivo 002.txt e assim por diante ....ou voce quer criar varios arquivos de uma só tacada?

Comment: Sim, é. Pesquise pela função `fopen` do PHP.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim, se o arquivo existir criar o próximo.

Comment: então tem que usar a função file_exists  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php

Comment: você já desenvolveu algum código para criar o arquivo?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim.

Comment: então edite sua pergunta e coloque seu codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de ver tanta negatividade no outros 2 comentários (inclusive o meu) resolvi fazer uma função recursiva para esta questão.

Esta função pode ter 2 ou 3 usos diferente e acho que um deles é a resposta para a tua pergunta.

**1º uso** - Podes verificar num intervalo ex: `[0..10]` se os todos os ficheiros existem, se alguns deles não existir, ira ser criado.

```
function createFiles($manyfiles = 0, $path, $indice = 0, $count = 0){
$num = 0;
$count++;

for ($i = $indice; $i < $manyfiles; $i++) { 
    $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $num) . ".txt";

    // verifica se é a primeira ve que entra no loop
    if($i == 0){

        // verifica se o primeiro ficheiro existe
        if(!file_exists($namePathFile)){

            echo "Criar primeiro arquivo se não existe<br>";
            $file = fopen($namePathFile, "w");

            // vamos fechar o ficheiro para não ficar em memoria
            fclose($file);

            // chamamos novamente a função mas retirando uma posição de cada
            return createFiles($manyfiles - 1, $path, $i, $count - 1);
        }
    }

    $num ++;
    //reformata o nome usando a variavel count
    $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $count) . ".txt";

    // verifica se o ficheiro atual existe
    if(!file_exists($namePathFile)){

        echo "criar arquivo " . $namePathFile . " <br>";


        $arquivo = fopen($namePathFile, "w") or die("Impossivel abrir o arquivo!");
        fclose($arquivo);

        //Cchama a função novamente retirando o valor que ja passou.
        return createFiles($manyfiles - $num, $path, $num, $count);
    }else{
        return createFiles($manyfiles - $num , $path, 0, $count);
    }

}

}
```

**2º Uso** - tens 3 ficheiros exemplo:

`001.txt`
`002.txt`
`004.txt`

este função ira adicionar o ficheiro em falta `003.txt`e mais nº quantidade de ficheiros(manyFiles) menos os ficheiros adicionados em falta(`003.txt`).

```
function createFiles($manyfiles = 0, $path, $indice = 0, $count = 0){
    $num = 0;
    $count++;

    for ($i = $indice; $i < $manyfiles; $i++) { 
        $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $num) . ".txt";

        // verifica se é a primeira ve que entra no loop
        if($i == 0){

            // verifica se o primeiro ficheiro existe
            if(!file_exists($namePathFile)){

                echo "Criar primeiro arquivo se não existe<br>";
                $file = fopen($namePathFile, "w");

                // vamos fechar o ficheiro para não ficar em memoria
                fclose($file);

                // chamamos novamente a função mas retirando uma posição de cada
                return createFiles($manyfiles - 1, $path, $i, $count - 1);
            }
        }

        $num ++;
        //reformata o nome usando a variavel count
        $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $count) . ".txt";

        // verifica se o ficheiro atual existe
        if(!file_exists($namePathFile)){

            echo "criar arquivo " . $namePathFile . " <br>";


            $arquivo = fopen($namePathFile, "w") or die("Impossivel abrir o arquivo!");
            fclose($arquivo);

            //Cchama a função novamente retirando o valor que ja passou.
            return createFiles($manyfiles - $num, $path, $num, $count);
        }else{
            return createFiles($manyfiles , $path, 0, $count);
        }

    }

}
```

**3º Uso**
- tens 3 ficheiros exemplo:

`001.txt`
`002.txt`
`004.txt`

Esta função ira criar o arquivo `003.txt` e na proxima execução (se todos os arquivos em ordem existirem) ira adicionar o ficheiro `005.txt`

```
function createFiles($manyfiles = 0, $path, $indice = 0, $count = 0){
    $num = 0;
    $count++;

    for ($i = $indice; $i <= $manyfiles; $i++) { 
        $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $num) . ".txt";

        // verifica se é a primeira ve que entra no loop
        if($i == 0){

            // verifica se o primeiro ficheiro existe
            if(!file_exists($namePathFile)){
                //echo "Criar primeiro arquivo se não existe<br>";
                $file = fopen($namePathFile, "w");
                // vamos fechar o ficheiro para não ficar em memoria
                fclose($file);
                return createFiles($manyfiles - 1, $path, $i, $count - 1);
            }
        }
        //reformata o nome usando a variavel count
        $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $count ) . ".txt";

        // verifica se o ficheiro atual existe
        if(file_exists($namePathFile)){

            $num ++;

            echo "criar arquivo " . $namePathFile . " <br>";

            $arquivo = fopen($namePathFile, "w") or die("Impossivel abrir o arquivo!");
            fclose($arquivo);

            //Cchama a função novamente retirando o valor que ja passou.
            return createFiles($manyfiles - $num, $path, $num, $count);

        }else{
            $namePathFile = $path . sprintf('%03d', $count ) . ".txt";
            $arquivo = fopen($namePathFile, "w") or die("Impossivel abrir o arquivo!");
            fclose($arquivo);
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Para executares uma destas funções basta 2 argumentos, exemplo:

```
createFiles(10, 'ficheiros/');
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: não fui eu quem negativou mas, cá pra nós, isso fez um bem tremendo nas respostas, hahaha rs